# BibTeX not working in Ubuntu 18 on Atom

Tags: bibtex, atom

I just recently migrated to Ubuntu 18 and I am trying to setup LaTeX as I use to run it on Mac. I compile LaTeX using Atom (with packages `latex` and `language-latex`). BibTeX however is not working. When I use the `\cite{}` command Atom doesn't pop the usual dropdown frame where the different references would appear as I type. Trying to run anyway with a citation key produced no citation or bibliography, without errors but with warnings that the reference was undefined. What is the error?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-2]
\cite{einstein}

\bibliography{/home/user/Desktop/bibtex.bib}

\end{document}
```

MWE of bib file (which is on the desktop):

```
@article{einstein,
    author =       "Albert Einstein",
    title =        "{Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter K{\"o}rper}. ({German})
        [{On} the electrodynamics of moving bodies]",
    journal =      "Annalen der Physik",
    volume =       "322",
    number =       "10",
    pages =        "891--921",
    year =         "1905",
    DOI =          "http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/andp.19053221004"
}
```

Comment: Did you press an extra button to generate the bibliography?

Comment: Extra button? How do I do that? Never had to do that. Back in mac os I just had to compile with ctrl+alt+b

Comment: You have to use an extra program to generate the bibliography for LaTeX. Maybe you id run an automation tool in the past. I don't know what button you have to press, as a vim user I would do `:! latexmk -pdf %`

Comment: How do you even run that command?

Comment: `\bibliography{/home/user/Desktop/bibtex.bib}` the ending `.bib` is not allowed. You should bet a warning or error message from bibtex.

Comment: @Johannes_B Ok, without the .bib extension the bibliography is produced, but I still don't get the autocompletion/suggestions when typing \cite{} commandes.